# What's the proper way to qualify a coconut whose coir has been removed?

Tags: word-request

With [coir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coir):

[image]

Without [coir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coir):

[image]

What's the proper way to qualify a coconut whose coir has been removed? E.g., is there some adjective for that?

---

As [Benjamin Harman](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/28425/benjamin-harman) [explains](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/284975/3023) regarding the second picture:

> That isn't a husked cocoanut, though. It's only partially husked. The [coir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coir):, the coarse fiber of the outer husk of a cocoanut, is just that, the outer husk. The inner husk still remains. Just the coir of that cocoanut's husk has been removed, so only the outer surface of the husk has been removed. The remainder of the husk remains, so that's not a husked cocoanut but at best a partially husked cocoanut, the part that is the coir being the only part of the husk that's been removed.

Comment: What do you mean, "qualify"?

Comment: Coconuts (preferred spelling) were not a common item in the areas where the English language originated and as a result there are very few words that are going to apply to specific degrees of coconut *de-husking*.  *Coir* is a new word to me, I'm just learning it today.  If such words do exists they would most likely be borrowed local words used in areas where coconuts grow.  I would refer to the degrees of de-husking as you have already - *Husked with only the brown outer husk removed and the inner husk remaining*.

Comment: This is more of an encyclopedia question.  You may need some technical jargon for this.  Wikipedia says - *Like other fruits, it has three layers: the exocarp, mesocarp, and endocarp.*  Search coconut on Wikipedia.